# How to pinpoint serialisation errors on Web API endpoints?

Tags: c#, debugging, vue.js, asp.net-core, axios

At times I have an endpoint on my web api:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task Foo([FromForm] int[] a, [FromForm] int b, ...) {
  await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

When calling this from the client side using axios:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('a', this.selected.map(n => n.id));
formData.append('b', this.id);
await this.axios.post('/api/v1/foo', formData);
```

I get a 400 error. Which states in no way of which field caused the issue. Is there a way of finding out other than trial and error?

> POST https://localhost:5001/api/v1/foo 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: `400` is most commonly due to bad syntax in the URL which causes the URL to be malformed, as in, the server is unable to break the URL in its component parts. Note your question has **nothing** to do with Vue as you'd have the exact same problem if you tryed a POST request to that URL regardless of the client side technology. It's all down to the what you're using on server-side. The server is issuing the `400` and that's where you have to look for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Asp.Net Core Api, if you check the web browser network tab, you will see below which already return the expected error response.

```
{
    "errors": {
        "a": [
            "The value '1,2,3' is not valid."
        ]
    },
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "8000001e-0004-fe00-b63f-84710c7967bb"
}
```

If you want to capture the errors by `axios`, you could try

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('a', "1,2,3");
formData.append('b', "1");
axios.post('/api/values/Foo', formData)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error.response.data.errors));
    });
```